# How to binding and take only the time of a datetime property in the view of a MAUI project?

Tags: maui

I have a view that has a label. The text of the label binds to a DateTime property. I would like to show only the date.

I am trying this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat='yyyy/MM/dd'}" />
```

The problem is that it is showm yyyy/MM/dd instead of the date.

If I use this way in a WPF application it works, so perhaps the bahavior is different in MAUI.

How could I show only the date and not the time?

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Thanks. In the documentation I could find a table with some format specifiers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings. But I can't find the format that I want. Also in the examples use formats like 0:c, 0:F4, 0:E7 that it tells what is in this example, but it makes me think that there are much formats.

Comment: try '{0:yyyy/MM/dd}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In StringFormat parameter you need to specify index of variable u passing from Binding => you have only one so index is number 0:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat='{0}'}" />
```

and if you want to use formatting you need to add colon after index and write your format after that colon:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" />
```

This will show a short date formatted DateTime.

I am new to MAUI, so maybe someone can describe it better, but basically this is what I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and register your own ValueConverter.

```
public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter,    CultureInfo culture)
{
    DateTime? date = value as DateTime?;
    return date?.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```